# How to fix Ros2 foxy install error on ubuntu mate?

Tags: ubuntu, ros

Trying to install ros2 foxy on ubuntu mate jelly jammyfish 22.04.1 got me errors

https://youtu.be/uWzOk0nkTcI
Following this tutorial by Articulated robotics, i tried to install ros2 foxy on my ubuntu mate jammy jellyfish 22.04.1 LTS.
I was not able to install it as shown by these errors:`
(commands from website given in video:https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html)

```
chrisbisi@chrisbisi-UX310UA:~$ sudo apt install ros-foxy-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-desktop
```

I had installed git and also had made a clone of this repo in my github acc:https://github.com/Chrisjubin/my_bot
(based off of the template given by articulated robotics aka joshnewans)
I am trying to run ros for a robot following articulated robotics' tutorial.
This is the part where i was told to get the github
repo:https://youtu.be/OWeLUSzxMsw?t=548

Answer (score 0):

According to the [REP 2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#foxy-fitzroy-may-2020-may-2023), foxy is meant for `Ubuntu 20.04` (which is the distribution used in the video you linked).
You can, however, try to use a dockerized solution. My suggestion would be to reinstall `Ubuntu 20.04` unless you have good reasons to be using `22.04`

Comment: thank you so much, i have gotten it installed.
Could you help me with one more thing,.. do you have any idea on how i can install the same (ubuntu mate 20.04.5 focal fossa) on raspberry pi, will it work on the pi?\

Comment: seems that you would need to check your raspberry pi version.  There is a way for [pi 4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348560/is-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-for-raspberry-pi-4-no-longer-available). Installing ROS shouldn't be an issue. I haven't tried though.